# What is the technical argument for this easy transformation?

Tags: calculus, probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In a book I found the following equation
$$P(\forall s \in (0,h]~:~X_s \in D)=\inf_nP(\forall s\in (\frac{1}{n},h] ~:~X_s\in D).$$
where $X_s$ is some stochastic process starting in a set $D$.
While it looked obvious to me at first, I have now asked myself what exactly is the technical argument behind this transformation. Is it some kind of continuity from above/below? Why did the author write $\inf$ instead of $\lim$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E_t$ be the subset of the universe corresponding to $\forall s \in (t,h], X_s \in D$.

Then $E_0$ is the decreasing intersection of the $E_{1/n}$. The equation is simply monotone continuity for probabilities.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any special reason why the author uses $\inf$ instead of $\lim$?

Comment: There unfortunately isn't an operator for "limit of this decreasing nonnegative thus converging sequence", which $\inf$ and $\lim$ can only partially represent. Both, of course, are correct in this case. I suppose that $\inf$ simply fit his idea better at that moment.

Comment: It's a basic fact of real analysis that the limit of a sequence which is decreasing and bounded above is the same as the infimum. So in effect the author did write "lim" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lemma_2  (The bound from above is $\mathbb{P}(E_1)$